# Class Loaders : Delegation Hierarchy Algorithm

Tags: java

As we know Class Loader sub system uses "Delegation Hierarchy Algorithm" to load the class. I am curious to understand the behaviour or logic behind its implementation. i.e  Even if the class is present in current directory (Application/System class loader may knew about it) still "Boot Strap Loader" gets priority and it delegates to its child. Can't this be changed or improved ?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you may change this behavior, but very very strange problems may arise.

Imagine you have multi-tier classloaders:

E.g. your classloader -> some parent classloader (e.g. webapp container classloader) -> system+bootsrap classloaders.

So now your code tries to load let's say ImmutableMap from guava, and guava.jar is visible for both "your classloader" and "webapp container classloader".

You decided not to delegate, but instead load it by yourself. That's how you got your instance of ImmutableMap. On another side, somehow "webapp container classloader" also loaded his own ImmutableMap from his own guava.jar file - because at that point he had no access to "your classloader" and the only way was to load missing stuff by himself.

So now you have two ImmutableMap classes, which are considered different (because loaded by different classloaders), and which may be really different if you have loaded them from different versions of guava.jar. But that's still "ok" so far.
The hell happens when you try to pass an instance of that ImmutableMap class across the boundary to webapp code - that's where ClassCastException happens, with a strange message "ImmutableMap class can't be cast to ImmutableMap".

To avoid that always call parent classloader first.

If you are 100% sure that instance of object of the class would never be passed to class that was load with different classloader - then you are safe - but you are never 100% sure.

Some framework related classloaders don't delegate(e.g. Jboss, and maybe some SpringBoot magical classes) but they perfectly know what are they doing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess following could be the reasons for this logic/implementation

1. As Object is the Parent of all the Classes in Java which resides in "java.lang" package & this package resides in "rt.jar" hence priority might be given to "Bootstrap Class Loader"
2. Most of the custom 
   classes needs Built-in Java Language features to be used like using String or int whose definition is available again in "rt.jar" & this will be loaded by "Bootstrap Class Loader" hence the priority might be given to it.